# C storing List of Lists of structs

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to hold multiple lists of structs of the following specification,

```
typedef struct Example
{
   int num1;
   int num2;
   char* str;
} Example;
```

I'm creating these lists from user / file input so the size of each list needs to be dynamic.

I would also need to store the length of each list, so I think I'd need another struct to hold a list of examples and it's size.

```
typedef struct ListOfExamples
{
    int length;
    Example** examples;
} ListOfExamples;
```

If I wanted to store a list of ListOfExample the type would be the following if I'm not mistaken,

```
ListOfExample** listOfExampleLists;
```

Is there a cleaner / easier way I could store lists of lists of Examples? It seems like a lot of memory allocation for this task and I'm new to C so I wanted to know if this was the best way to do this.

Comment: *"...if I'm not mistaken"* - you're mistaken. A simple dynamic sequence of some struct type can be done with single indirection. I.e. `ListOfExample *listOfExampleLists = malloc(N * sizeof *listOfExampleLists);` for example. It's also probable you're needlessly using one too many levels of indirection in your `ListOfExamples`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to allocate the string of each structure separately it will become a pain to free the whole things. Instead you could use a fixed size string and ensure you never use one longer than that limit (here 31 since the last character is the null termination ), this way the string is allocated with the structure :

```
typedef struct Example
{
   int num1;
   int num2;
   char str[32];
} Example;
```

In the list of structures you should use a simple pointer rather than a double pointer. Better, you can use a flexible array :

```
typedef struct ListOfExamples
{
    int length;
    Example examples[];
} ListOfExamples;
```

This way the size of your ListOfExamples will be only 4 bytes.  If you have 100 lists of lists whose each has a length of 100, the whole stuff will use 400 kilobytes (4 * 100 * 100) + 400 bytes for the list of lists.

Then you can use it like this :

```
int main() { 

     // For the list of lists you could create a list pointers on the stack with all pointers set to NULL:
     ListOfExamples * listOfList[100] = {0};
     
     // Sets the first index of listOfList with an allocated list of size 100 :
    listOfList[0] = (ListOfExamples *)malloc(sizeof(ListOfExamples) + 100 * sizeof(Example));
    listOfList[0]->length = 100;

     // The memory for each example is already allocated, you just need to use it :
     Example * ex = &listOfList[0]->examples[0];
     ex->num1 = 27;
     ex->num2 = 10;
     // The string must be set using memcpy
     memcpy(ex->str, "My Birthday", sizeof("My Birthday")); 

    // Read a structure
    Example first = listOfList[0]->examples[0];
    printf("%d %d %s", first.num1, first.num2, first.str);

    // Finally free the used lists
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { 
        if (listOfList[i]) free(listOfList[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes an example on how you could adapt your code, I think the pointer names I've put explains almost everything:

The trick here is that each element of the second list is a pointer to the first element. And since it is a list, it must contain a reference to the next element of its type. (You might want to keep this lenght field outside the list - a normal variable - if its intent is only to count how many elements are currently in the list)

```
typedef struct Example
{
   int num1;
   int num2;
   char* str;
   struct Example *next;
 } Example;

typedef struct ListOfExamples
{
   int length;
   Example* examples;
   struct ListOfExamples *nextList; 
} ListOfExamples;

int main() {
   Example *second, *ex; //ex will be the first element of the first list
   ex = (Example*)malloc(sizeof(Example));
   second = (Example*)malloc(sizeof(Example));
   ex->num1 = ex->num2 = 10;
   second->num1 = second->num2 = 5;
   ex->next = second;
   second->next = NULL;

   ListOfExamples *listoflist = (ListOfExamples*) malloc(sizeof(ListOfExamples));
   listoflist->examples = ex;
   listoflist->nextList = NULL;

   printf("%d\n", listoflist->examples->num1);
   printf("%d\n", listoflist->examples->next->num1);
}
```